# Put string resource into bundle in android

Tags: android

I have following problem

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("url", "someUrl");
```

This works fine. But

```
bundle.putString("title", R.string.titleForUrl);
```

Eclipse notes that `R.string.titleForUrl` is an int but should be string. But isn't `R.string.titleForUrl` a string?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R.string.titleForUrls is an integer, which is a resource identifier into the string table.

To obtain the string you need to call context.getString(R.string.titleForUrls) to load the string from the resource.

Therefore if you wish to store the string then you can either pass the loaded string or the int and then load when you get the int from the bundle on the other side.

Answer (score 5):

use this

```
bundle.putString("title",getString(R.string.titleForUrl);
```

Answer (score 2):

`R.string.titleForUrl` is a resource id. It is an int that stands for a String resource. You can get the String from this resource id using `yourActivity.getResources().getString(.string.titleForUrl)`.

For more information see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html) and here.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is an int.  `R.string.titleForUrl` is an ID number for a string variable that you have loaded from an xml document.  What you want is something like this:

`bundle.putString("title", getResources().getString(R.string.titleForUrl);`

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question has already been answered completely some time ago, I'd like to add the following since your questions ranks pretty high on google:

Bundle keys should not be realized by String resources (as also noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870988/should-i-be-storing-strings-that-i-use-as-keys-inside-android-bundles-as-a-resou)) for these reasons:

1. They are never visually presented to the user
2. Because of 1. there is no need to translate them, so the *translatable* attribute in your xml should always be set to *false* to avoid lint errors
3. They are accessed programmatically only and not included in a layout or other .xml files

**Conclusion:** Using *final static Strings* should be your preffered way of using bundle keys

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin way:

```
val bundle = Bundle().apply {this.putString("yourKey", "your string value")}
```