# Should I be storing strings that I use as keys inside Android Bundles as a resource?

Tags: android, android-resources

Is it generally good practice not to hardcode strings used as keys in dictionaries, maps and extras bundles etc, or does it matter?

```
extras.putSerializable("myKey", getItem(thisIndex).getSomeObject());
```

verses

```
extras.putSerializable(ctx.getString(R.string.my_key), getItem(thisIndex).getSomeObject());
```

I'm doing the following when instantiating fragments and associating a page title with the fragment for use with a page title indicator

```
    Bundle pageTitle = new Bundle();
    pageTitle.putSerializable(getString(R.string.page_title_key), getString(R.string.somePageTitle));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MyPageFragment.class.getName(), pageTitle));
```

Then in my FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position).getArguments().getSerializable(ctx.getString(R.string.page_title_key)).toString();
}
```

Comment: <PutFlameProofSuitOn> I believe that the only strings that you should move into resources are those that might change, e.g. text used in the UI that you might want to localise.  IMHO, the name of a key is never seen outside your code so apart from a (little stretched out) argument about maintainability, I would hard code the string and avoid the overhead of the getString call.  One small enhancement might be to use a static final String to hold the value as a field of your class which goes some way to addressing the maintenance thing.  The compiler will inline it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good programming and the MVC model would say to not hard code your key. I also would not put it in your strings resource. Instead, I prefer to use constants. If you define them as `public static` other classes will be able to reference the same data as well. That way you only need to type out the actual key once in your code.

Comment: right but sometimes, like in my example, i need to use a key in different classes. one activity puts one and some other class will need to access it.

Comment: Your fragments should be driven by a single main activity and thus a public static final String SOME_KEY = "somekey"; should suffice.

Comment: As tencent hinted at, you can defined public static variables and access them from all your classes. And then you can feel good for being a superhero programmer.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you should be using the resource strings is when it makes sense. Should you need to translate your application to Spanish, French, Russian, etc. will you need your internal naming translated? Probably not. I use constants (final) for internal fragment naming. It makes the most sense in my opinion.

For the visible naming of the fragments, say for a tabbed display. Yes, use the string resources. They are your friend.